# What was the first "Siddur" prayer / section?

Tags: tefilla, history, prayer-book

Outside of Shema and the Amidah, can someone explain the chronology of what sections of the Siddur service as we currently have them were added? E.g. was *Psukei Dezimra* added first? Blessings before / after Shema? Which ones?

Also, which tefillah was developed first - weekday Shacharit, mincha, etc.?

As a "bonus" to your answer, I'd greatly appreciate if you can find an online or book source that lists the "chronology" of the prayers that were added to the Siddur.

Comment: For sections which predate the Talmud it's quite difficult to imagine someone providing a chronology

Comment: The blessings before and after the Shema are mentioned in the Mishnah for sure, just as the 18 blessings.